# how to redirect back to login after creating an account in redux saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, redux, redux-saga

im new to redux-saga, and i'm not very sure why can't i be redirected back to login page after creating an account? i've included the necessary codes to enable the redirection but i'm always given a blank page upon signing up.

***action.js***

```
export const registerUser = (user, history) => ({
  type: REGISTER_USER,
  payload: { user, history },
});
export const registerUserSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS,
  payload: user,
});
export const registerUserError = (message) => ({
  type: REGISTER_USER_ERROR,
  payload: { message },
});
```

***reducer.js***

```
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        currentUser: action.payload,
        error: '',
      };
    case REGISTER_USER_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        currentUser: null,
        error: action.payload.message,
      };
  }
};
```

***saga.js***

```
const registerWithEmailPasswordAsync = async (email, password, username) => {
  const data = await axios.post(
    `${baseUrl}auth/signup`,
    { username, password, email },
    { headers }
  );
  return data;
};

function* registerWithEmailPassword({ payload }) {
  const { email, password, username } = payload.user;
  const { history } = payload;
  try {
    const registerUser = yield call(
      registerWithEmailPasswordAsync,
      email,
      password,
      username
    );
    if (!registerUser.message) {
      const item = { uid: registerUser.user.uid, ...currentUser };
      setCurrentUser(item);
      yield put(registerUserSuccess(item));
      history.push(adminRoot);
    } else {
      yield put(registerUserError(registerUser.message));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(registerUserError(error));
  }
}

export function* watchRegisterUser() {
  yield takeEvery(REGISTER_USER, registerWithEmailPassword);
}
```

***register form***

```
            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onUserRegister}>
              {({ errors, touched }) => (
                <Form className="av-tooltip tooltip-label-bottom">
                  <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                    <Label>
                      <IntlMessages id="user.fullname" />
                    </Label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      name="username"
                      placeholder="John Doe"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                    <Label>
                      <IntlMessages id="user.email" />
                    </Label>
                    <Field
                      name="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      validate={validateEmail}
                      placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
                    />
                    {errors.email && touched.email && (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                        {errors.email}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                    <Label>
                      <IntlMessages id="user.password" />
                    </Label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Enter Password"
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      validate={validatePassword}
                    />
                    {errors.password && touched.password && (
                      <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
                        {errors.password}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                    <Label>
                      <IntlMessages id="user.repeat-password" />
                    </Label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      name="repeatPassword"
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Repeat Password"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <Button
                      type="submit"
                      color="primary"
                      className={`btn-shadow btn-multiple-state btn-login ${
                        loading ? 'show-spinner' : ''
                      }`}
                    >
                      <span className="spinner d-inline-block">
                        <span className="bounce1" />
                        <span className="bounce2" />
                        <span className="bounce3" />
                      </span>
                      <span className="label">
                        <IntlMessages id="user.register-button" />
                      </span>
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              )}
            </Formik>
```

i'm using formik to render the form, but i dont think it really matters what form im using. i mainly can't figure out the saga part that handles the redirection. any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Seems like the right idea - where does `adminRoot` come from? Does your router properly recognize and handle whatever route it refers to? If you're getting a blank page my guess is it's not an issue with the saga since the only time the history is changed right now is after the login succeeds in the saga.

Comment: adminRoot is used as part of a default value

`export const adminRoot = '/app';`

Comment: Try something like `history.push("/hello-world");` and check if the URL in browser become `/hello-world` or not.

Comment: the URL remains as `http://localhost:3000/user/register`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have managed to solved the problem after multiple attempts.

Turns out that `const item = { uid: registerUser.user.uid, ...currentUser };` is actually pointing to the wrong db. Removed it and set to the correct db and everything worked like a charm.

so final codes in **saga.js** is:

```
function* registerWithEmailPassword({ payload }) {
  const { email, password, username } = payload.user;
  const { history } = payload;
  try {
    const registerUser = yield call(
      registerWithEmailPasswordAsync,
      email,
      password,
      username
    );
    if (!registerUser.message) {
      setCurrentUser(registerUser.data); <-- correct db
      yield put(registerUserSuccess(registerUser.data));
      history.push(adminRoot);
    } else {
      yield put(registerUserError(registerUser.message));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(registerUserError(error));
  }
}
```